# how to unlocalize theme/plugin?

Tags: theme-development, translation, localization

I have theme with this code in one php file :

```
'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">'.
                    sprintf( __( 'Logged in as <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>', 'testshop' ),
                    admin_url( 'profile.php' ),
                    $user_identity,
                    wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ).
                  '</p>',
```

Now I want to change this code and unlocalized and only one text.

I change this to code below , but not work and get the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

```
'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">'.
                    echo ( 'Logged in as <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>'),
                    admin_url( 'profile.php' ),
                    $user_identity,
                    wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ).
                  '</p>',
```

please help me to fix this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you removed the sprintf.

Replace the echo with sprintf and remove the ().

Should be like this

```
'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">'.
                    sprintf( 'Logged in as <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>',
                    admin_url( 'profile.php' ),
                    $user_identity,
                    wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ).
                  '</p>',
```

Be careful! changing code directly in a plugin will lead to problems.

Next plugin update your code will be removed so be mindful.

If you can try using a filter, if the plugin has one. That way the changed you are doing when connecting to that filter will stay, unless the plugin author changed the filter name =]

Comment: Thanks and what change this code need? ----> : <p class="message"><?php echo sprintf(_n('You have 1 item in your shopping cart','You have %d items in your shopping cart', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'testshop'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?></p>

Comment: What do you mean what change? also removing localization?

Comment: With this change , i want to develope custom theme and only for one language (not need to localization ).

Comment: Going by the functionality of _n I would do something like this. `sprintf(($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 1 ? 'You have 1 item in your shopping cart' : 'You have %d items in your shopping cart'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);`

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot